# Where in the user account directory does Crystal Reports store temp files?

Tags: crystal-reports

There's an error in crystal reports that says access to a report file is denied because "another program may be using it". This is commonly cited as being resolved by giving the proper permissions to the "C:\Windows\Temp" directory.

However, I've also encountered a permutation during local debugging for Visual Studio in which the error had to be resolved by setting permissions on a folder somewhere under the "C:\Users[Username]" directory. I figured it out once or twice, but under circumstances in which I didn't take note of the directory name for later reference.

Can someone tell me where Crystal Reports stores its temporary files for individual user accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal Reports saves its temporary files in a directory which is based on the Environment Variables of the OS.

Usually the default directory for Windows 7 is C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp but there are better ways to determine it dynamically.

1. Go to `Computer → Properties → Advanced system settings → Advanced → Environment variables` find the TEMP variable in the User variables for [Username]
2. Run cmd.exe, type echo %temp% and hit enter

To test the path, we can generate temp files from the Crystal Reports Engine by just connecting a report file to a Crystal Reports Viewer and running the code. This process will generate temp files in the temp path.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
End Sub
```

The temp files will look something like the following:

temp_0194c263-1a68-493f-94f1-9c3911cb0c7d {8D3CD485-167C-4DDB-AD91-A8586B36459A}.rpt
temp_0194c263-1a68-493f-94f1-9c3911cb0c7d.rpt
~cpe{F9155453-1E39-42B6-846D-07C8497B0373}.tmp
~DF0DC28410DCDF26A9.TMP

Comment: The `TMP` environment variable is also used (Crystal Reports Engine version 13.0.2000.0)